# Joomla: Limiting hotlinking access to images and video

Tags: php, joomla

I hope i get help soon :)

The Problem simply is this:
I built a custom component(php software) which will soon be listed on Joomla Extension directory for users to download. In this component, images and videos are linked to via urls (hotlinked).

Now on my website, users are made to pay for subscription.

Want i want to achieve is simply to allow the component i built to be granted access to images and videos to users who have an active subscription on my website, and restrict the component access to images and videos to users whose subscription has expired.

I just need an idea of how to go about this. 
Your responses are Highly anticipated, thank you.

Comment: For those users who have subscribed, I assume you have an additional column which determines whether they have an active subscription. Such as `active = 0` and `active = 1`. You can simply write an `if else` statement

Comment: Thats simple enough to achieve. What i mean is for example you download my software and install on your web server, how does that software you downloaded check if your subscription is on or off on my webserver and i dont want to place the full url to the images if subscription is true. Because some programmers may be able to sniff through the code and turn off the local if else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I understand you would allow the component to be downloaded freely, but it won't display the hotlinked media to expired suscribers or not registered users.

I guess you would have to keep your registered user host in a table, and instead of hotlinking to the image directly serve it through a php script that would check subscription status (based on the request host url) before displaying the image or a "unsuscribed" fallback image.

The other way would be to restring the content in your webserver, either in .htaccess or in the vhost definition of nginx. But this would mean to manually add or remove suscribers constantly.

**Very loose example:** your suscriber request the image as

```
<img src="http://yoursite.com/image.php?img=akdbnrieodoidnsd"/>
```

from his site http://suscribersite.com

Your image script is the following

```
$imghash=$_GET['img'];
//strip non alphanumeric characters, to avoid malicious requests
$cleanhash =preg_replace('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i','', $imghash);

header('content-type: image/png');
if(valid_suscriber($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $img = file_get_contents("/non-public-directory/$cleanhash.png");
} else {
    $img = file_get_contents("/non-public-directory/unauthorized.png");
}

echo $img;
```

You'll have to implement the **valid_suscriber** function to check the http_referer **suscribersite.com** against your suscriber table. Be warned, though, the **http_referer can be easily spoofed**.

The real solution to your case would be to perform an oauth handshake prior to any request, and append the oauth token to each subsequent request. This is much more cumbersome but less prone to tampering.

Comment: Very Nice idea. For example lets say all users had license keys, how would i make the extension query my webserver database to check if the licence is active?

Comment: Yep that idea definitely did it for me. thanks amenadiel